# How do I add a date format to custom block output

Tags: 7, datetime

I have two custom block output fields that are date

```
    function my_three_upcoming_events() {
  $output = '';
  $now_events = views_get_view_result('schedule_list2');
  $upcoming_events = views_get_view_result('clone_of_now');
  $max_events = 3;

  $all_events = array_merge($now_events, $upcoming_events);
/*   print_r ('<pre>');
print_r ($all_events);
exit();
*/  for ($i=0,$z=$max_events;$i<$z;$i++) {

    $node = node_load($all_events[$i]->nid);
    $output .='<div>' . l($node->title,'/node/'.$node->nid) . '</div>';
    $output .='<div>' .($node->body[und][0][value]) . '</div>';
    $output .='<div>' .($node->field_venue[und][0][value]) . '</div>';
    $output .='<div>' .($node->field_session_start_date[und][0][value]) . '</div>';
    $output .='<div>' .($node->field_session_start_date[und][0][value2]) . '</div>';







  }


}
```

and they output like this

2014-04-18 15:15:00
2014-04-19 21:15:00

How can I change to one of the php date formats

Thanks for any help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [date_format](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_date/7) (Drupal function).

Comment: So just to clarify insert the function where the outputs fields are being set into date_format

Comment: Just add the date field's value as the timestamp for the date_format function and pass it the date type to use (custom is also an option)